# Date comparison function in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, datetime

I am trying to display records which are created after Oct 1 2010. But my query doesn't seem to work. It also display records from 2004 - Sept 2010 which is not wanted.

What is wrong with the query below?

```
select Distinct app.app_id,
  (convert(varchar, creation_date,101) + ' ' +  convert(varchar,creation_date ,108)) as creation_date,
  dbo.oea_fn_get_amc_mem_name(app.app_id,primary_msn,getdate(), 'EN', 30000) PIName,
  dbo.oea_fn_get_pid_countyname(app.app_id,primary_msn,'OC')as PIpid,
  primary_msn,
  zip,
  home_tel,
  work_tel,
  work_extn,
  other_contact,
  other_ext,
  cell_tel,

  dbo.oea_fn_get_amc_mem_name(app.app_id,mem.msn,getdate(), 'EN', 30000)as Kname,
  dbo.oea_fn_get_pid_countyname(app.app_id,mem.msn,'OC')as Knamepid,
  mem.msn as Kmsn,
  (select count(reminder_id) from reminders (nolock) where app_id=app.app_id) as reminder

from app_application app  (nolock)
inner join app_member mem  with (nolock) on  app.app_id=mem.app_id 
--left outer join Oea_App_Program_Disposition disp with (nolock) on mem.app_id = disp.app_id and mem.msn=disp.msn
inner join app_address aadd with (nolock) on app.app_id=aadd.app_id
--inner join app_calc_results calc  with (nolock) on mem.app_id=calc.app_id and calc.msn=mem.msn
left outer join app_member_benefits ben with (nolock) on mem.app_id = ben.app_id and mem.msn=ben.msn

where  
 isnull(mem.coverage_required,0) = 1
 and app.app_status = 's'
     and ben.ins_end_date < getdate()
     and app.client_id = 30000
     and app.app_id  not in (select app_id from app_renewal) 
     and (mem.msn in (select calc.msn from app_calc_results calc 
                 inner join app_application app on calc.app_id = app.app_id and calc.prog_id = 'CK' and calc.opt_out = 1))
     and (mem.msn in (select msn from app_calc_results where app_id=app.app_id and status not in ('A','X')))
     or (mem.msn in (select msn from Oea_App_Program_Disposition where app_id=app.app_id and disp_status not in ('A','P')) )
     and app.creation_date >= '10/01/2010'
```

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: On first glance, your problem is most likely that `or` in the where clause... anything that meets that condition, regardless of it's date, will be included.

Comment: If you comment out the Or clause, do you only get results from 2010-10-01?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
 and (
     (mem.msn in (select calc.msn from app_calc_results calc 
                 inner join app_application app on calc.app_id = app.app_id and calc.prog_id = 'CK' and calc.opt_out = 1))
    or (mem.msn in (select msn from app_calc_results where app_id=app.app_id and status not in ('A','X')))
    or (mem.msn in (select msn from Oea_App_Program_Disposition where app_id=app.app_id and disp_status not in ('A','P')) )
     )
 and app.creation_date >= '10/01/2010'
```

The problem is with the logic behind the or in the where clause.

Comment: Thanks.  Hmmm... all the other answers went away.  LOL.

Comment: @userstackoverflow - because your problem is with the `or` re-think the logic on what you want ored.  You might have to repeat some of the statements twice inside the two "sides" of the or.

Comment: Also, I would suggest indenting and lining up your parentheses so that you're sure that you have what you think you have.

Comment: @userstackoverflow - Took a guess at the logic... but only you know.  See edit.

Comment: Hogan...U are awesome. Thanks for the suggestion. Indenting and lining up of parentheses worked. Once again, Thank you. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, the problem is likely the Or clause in the Where clause. In effect, your query is:

```
Select ...
From ..
Where (A And B And C 
    And D And E 
    And F And G
    And app.creation_date >= '10/01/2010'
    )
    Or mem.msn In   (
                    Select msn 
                    From Oea_App_Program_Disposition 
                    Where app_id=app.app_id 
                        And disp_status not in ('A','P')
                    )
```

Thus, if for any row, if the `Or` is true, the rest of the "Ands" are ignored. I would assume that the `Or` is supposed to be paired with one of the `And` clauses.